# How do I install node.js if my package manager doesn't include it?

Tags: software-installation, cross-compilation, node.js

[Node.js](http://nodejs.org), server side javascript sitting on top of Google's v8 engine, is not available for install from the Debian squeeze's default repositories and doesn't easily compile for ARM. Are there any raspberry pi specific projects to get node up and running? Is there an easy way to build from source or install from binary if my package manager doesn't include node or if I want the latest version?

Comment: Sorry, but it works great on my Arch Linux Pi. Installed from repository.

Comment: Yeah the pacman install is great for Arch linux, but not for Debian/others. This is good for custom builds or if you aren't on Arch.

Comment: Check out the package build for Arch, perhaps you can copy that build proceedure?

Comment: It's a good suggestion, but if you look at my answer, someone's already done the legwork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Those patches are not necessary anymore since Node.js v0.8.10.**

1. Either compile it yourself (takes about 2 hours):
   http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=18775
2. Download the binary (at the moment only available for v0.8.17).
   http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.17/node-v0.8.17-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz

Answer (score 11):

Github user [Geoff Flarity](https://github.com/gflarity) has created a raspberry pi specific patch that allows [node.js](http://nodejs.org) to be compiled for the raspberry pi.

On top of this he includes pre-built binaries for the latest version of node and clear instructions.

You can find this all here https://github.com/gflarity/node_pi

Answer (score 3):

Under the Debian Squeeze distribution node.js 0.8.2 compiles quite happily with a few tweaks

http://ijosblog.blogspot.fi/2012/07/compiling-nodejs-on-raspberry-pi.html