# Pre-compiled Node.js for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, node.js, packages

Is there a precompiled binary of the latest [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) that runs on the Raspbian OS?

Comment: and i tried to add a 'nodejs' tag but i dont have enough awesomeness to do this here

Comment: You tried cross-compiling?

Comment: Are you asking the same as http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1078/86 ?

Comment: @alex: maybe its the same question. it might be OS specific, in which case its a different question

Comment: Totally, setup a Cross compiler to do it. It will save hours of compile time.

Comment: What operating system do you do?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: raspbian

Comment: and on your PC?

Comment: i use windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js distributes official pre-compiled binaries that works on Raspberry Pi:

```
cd /opt
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v9.4.0/node-v9.4.0-linux-armv6l.tar.xz
sudo tar xzf node-v9.4.0-linux-armv6l.tar.xz
sudo rm node-v9.4.0-linux-armv6l.tar.xz
sudo ln -s /opt/node-v9.4.0-linux-armv6l /opt/nodejs
sudo ln -s /opt/nodejs/bin/node /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -s /opt/nodejs/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```

To update later, just download and extract the new tar file as above and replace the '/opt/nodejs' symlink with the new release:

```
sudo unlink /opt/nodejs
sudo ln -s /opt/node-vX.X.X-linux-armv6l /opt/nodejs
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers to multiple questions. The system flags this as an attempt to game the system.

Comment: is his answer correct though? should I accept it? It looks better than the others here

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be cross-compiling. With that you can compile in your desktop machine and install into the RPi.

Take a look at http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=7493

Answer (score 1):

For more recent versions of node than other answers provide, Adafruit has a repository that, as of node `v0.12.0` contains pre-compiled node.js.

Essentially, add the repository in `Raspbian`

```
curl -sLS https://apt.adafruit.com/add | sudo bash
```

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install node
```

[Complete tutorial.](https://learn.adafruit.com/node-embedded-development/installing-node-dot-js) 
Note: Haven't tried this yet, but tutorial was published on `2014-12-19 at 04.57.54 PM` and updated `2015-05-04 at 04.27.57 PM` so seems more recent than other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to compile nodejs without issues using this method:

http://notetodogself.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-install-nodejs-on-rasberrypi.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a script that will install the **Latest** version of NodeJs. Don't wast the time to compile on a raspberry pi.  This will work for **all** raspberry pi's despite processor types (ARM6, ARM7), The scripts handles all of that. All you need to do is run this line of code:

```
sudo wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/audstanley/NodeJs-Raspberry-Pi/master/Install-Node.sh | bash
node -v;
```

source code is here: [GitHub: NodeJs-RaspberryPi](https://github.com/audstanley/NodeJs-Raspberry-Pi)